# nginx proxy not working server block

Tags: nginx, proxy

Im trying to setup a proxy on a subdir but cant make it work...

I want to proxy all requests in a subdir to another port

eg

```
http://domain.com/websocket/test.php => http://domain.com:8080/websocket/test.php
```

But cant make it work.. I have now tried to return `404` if a path matching `/websocket` is requested.. But that wont work either

What am I missing here?!

PHP files are executed as they should..

## file structure

```
/test.php
/websocket/server.php
/websocket/test.php
```

All URL's are requested without problems, but `/websocket/server.php` and `/websocket/test.php` should return `404` (look in the nginx conf)

## nginx

```
location / {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  php;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
}

location /websocket {
    return 404;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various types of `location` block and rules as to their evaluation order. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `location ~ ...` block is a regular expression type, that are evaluated in order but have a higher precedence than any prefix location (e.g. `location /websocket`).

If you want a prefix location to have higher precedence than the regular expression location blocks, either:
- use the `^~` modifier, or 
- turn it into a regular expression block and order it first.

For example:

```
location ^~ /websocket { ... }
```